# How do I start offering logo design services?

Tags: logo

Premise: I am not a graphic designer but I enjoy using Adobe Photoshop to create logos. I have been working with it for some time in the past, so I know how to use most of the functions and tools related to what I am asking (i.e., logo design).

I want to dedicate some of my free time to this and transform what is a personal, recreational activity to an actual service for actual users. I am an amateur so, of course, nothing like a real freelance job, but rather a way to start offering my works to people who might be interested in them.

My question is: do you know of any platform in which you can post offers or take charge of requests made by other users and getting paid for your work? I want to stress again the fact that I am doing it at a quite basic level and I am not planning at all to work for large clients or companies.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Sorry, but Photoshop is technically the wrong kind of software for designing logos.  You really need to master vector software such as Adobe Illustrator. Photoshop is a raster image editor.

Comment: See [this post](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/a/813) on the freelance site. Related posts here: [What should I add to my Graphic design skills to increase my job opportunities?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/154290/23061) and [How do I know when I'm ready to start doing professional work?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/25738/23061)

Comment: "do you know of any platform in which you can post offers or take charge of requests made by other users and getting paid for your work?" that sounds like Fiverr to me

Answer (score 4):

<sup>(Too long for a comment)</sup>

Small or large, you're seeking to compete with others. If you wish to sell anything.... someone else wants to also sell that very thing.

Just saying, be prepared for that. You can't "sell" your services *without* competing for those dollars. It's not unique to want to make money more as a hobbyist than a professional. Nonetheless hobbyists *do* compete with professionals (and vice versa) for those dollars.

There are a bunch of sites where you can compete for work... fiverr.com, upwork.com, guru.com, even etsy.com. Just do an internet search for "Sell Logo Designs" - you'll find many sites. Whether those sites will accept raster-based artwork for "logos" may be another matter (Billy is correct in his comment - Photoshop is *not* generally a viable "logo" creation tool). You'll have to check file requirements on each site.

What you're asking is no different for "basic level" work than it is for more professional level projects or clients. If you're selling *anything* creative, the general client hurdles you'll face are the same for a $5 project as they are for a $5,000 project. In fact, you may face *more* client issues if percieved as a novice or non-professional (i.e. you *may* get ripped off more.) You'll still need to operate as a business, pay taxes (if you make more than $600 in a year for the U.S.), invoice clients, etc. Essentially, you *will* be freelancing and all will need to deal with all which that entails. Just because you possibly don't anticipate making a living off the work, it doesn't change the fact you'll be seen and need to operate like *any* other freelancer.

There's no such thing as "easy money." If there were, we'd all be doing it.

---

An often easier path for hobbyists is to sell *art*, not "logos". Most royalty-free stock image sites accept *contributors*. You can draw/paint whatever you want, then upload it and offer it for sale. No client interactions or headaches. But no direct return on the work. If no one likes your art and it doesn't sell, you don't make any money. And for such situations, often the only way to make more than a few bucks a month is by having a large *quantity* of images available for sale.

Comment: it might not sell...  or it just might :) https://www.logaster.co.uk/blog/twitter-logo/#:~:text=Twitter%20bought%20the,oxley

Comment: What I got from that... Twitter broke the terms of service at a stock agency web site for 2 years. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Fiverr or Upwork are good places to start, there are many small clients needing logos for small businesses, and you can add to your experience and portfolio by doing small business logos.
2. Photoshop is not ideal for delivering scalable logos, consider learning Illustrator which works better with shapes and can produce vector format files, which are critical in logo design.